# How can I hide the console in PyQt5 (At a point in the program)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I know that I can set the format of the file to .pyw, but I want to hide the console at a point in the program. At some part of the program I want to hide the GUI, but sometimes I want the opposite. 
I am using the `win.setVisible(False)` command to hide the GUI, how can I do the same with the console?

Comment: You can't. Qt has absolutely no control over the shell/terminal/prompt from which it was started. Note that this is valid for almost any other framework in any system (except for very specific cases of Linux terminal emulators, but that's not your case).

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer your problem, but you can hide the console if you run your app with pythonw.exe

Comment: Okey, so I can't. Thank you for let me know it, should I make an answer that I can't and accept it, or just leave it open?. And Flavio Moraes I said that I know it.